# Map array of an array to an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, dictionary, object

I'm trying to convert an array within an array that looks like this

```
{ 
  active: 
    [ 'Company 1' ],
  inactive: 
    [ 'Company 2', 'Company 3'],
  archived:
    [ 'Company 4' ]
}
```

To an object that looks like this

```
[
  { state: 'active', company: 'company 1' },
  { state: 'inactive', company: 'company 2' },
  { state: 'inactive', company: 'company 3' },
  { state: 'archived', company: 'company 4' }
]
```

I'm sure this isn't to difficult, I just can't seem to get it right. Thanks.

EDIT: I realized I wrote the question somewhat wrong. I've got an array within an array and I need to convert it to an object within an array. The code above is exactly how it appears in my program currently.

Sorry about the confusion. See above for this change.

Comment: That's not a valid JS object, An object is a key-value pair `{ 'company 1' }`

Comment: Could you please post previous attempts?

Comment: I think what @decpk was trying to say is that an object should have key value pairs, eg `{ company: "Company 1" }`. FYI, arrays are defined via square brackets, eg `["Company 1", "Company 2", ...]`

Comment: Are you trying to convert `{ active: [ 'Company 1' ], inactive: [ 'Company 2', 'Company 3'], archived: [ 'Company 4' ]}` to `[{ state: 'active', company: 'company 1' }, { state: 'inactive', company: 'company 2' }, { state: 'inactive', company: 'company 3' }, { state: 'archived', company: 'company 4' }]`?

Comment: @Phil I deleted my previous comment because I realized what I missed, but thanks for taking the time to explain either way. I was thinking JSON(obviously not the same, but where my mind went), but then the keys are missing their quotes to be correct JSON format anyway

Comment: @decpk thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the question to better suit the result I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Input is perfect now but what about the output that you desire. It should be wrapped in an array, not an object. It should be `[
  { state: 'active', company: 'Company 1' },
  { state: 'inactive', company: 'Company 2' },
  { state: 'inactive', company: 'Company 3' },
  { state: 'archived', company: 'Company 4' }
]`

Comment: FYI, Array is an indexed collection and object is key-value pair.

Comment: @decpk you're totally right. Thanks for helping me through that, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const obj = {
  active: ["Company 1"],
  inactive: ["Company 2", "Company 3"],
  archived: ["Company 4"],
};

const result = Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([key, value]) =>
  value.map((v) => ({ state: key, company: v }))
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance that your object had typos and was actually the following, here's one possible solution. Also, the result is an array of objects, whereas your result is an object of objects (missing keys) so I assumed you actually wanted an array.

```js
let obj = {
  active: ['Company 1'],
  inactive: ['Company 2', 'Company 3'],
  archived: ['Company 4']
}

let newobj = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, a) => {
  a[1].forEach(company => acc.push({
    state: a[0],
    company: company
  }));
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(newobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `for...in` and `forEach`:

```js
const data = {
  active: ["Company 1"],
  inactive: ["Company 2", "Company 3"],
  archived: ["Company 4"],
};

const result = [];

for (const state in data) {
  data[state].forEach(company=>result.push({state,company}))
}

console.log(result);
```